# remove line from html input mask? (gravity forms)

Tags: html, css, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms, and there's this feature called "input masks" (which I assume is a standard html5 feature?) to force users to enter data in a specific format. However, it creates a line inside the input field. See image below:

[image: How to remove the line from text filed?]

How can I get rid of this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input mask functionality used by Gravity Forms is not a standard HTML5 feature. It is powered by this [Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). This script provides an option for setting the placeholder character (i.e. the underscore); however, there isn't a super easy way to enable this option with Gravity Forms' implementation.

Here's one method you might find useful.

1. Add an HTML field to your form.
2. Add the following code to your HTML field.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       setTimeout( function() {
           jQuery( '#input_FORMID_FIELDID' ).mask( 'MASK', { placeholder: '' } );
       }, 500 );
   </script>
   ```
3. Make the following updates to the code:

   - Replace MASK with your input mask template (i.e. '99999-?9999')
   - Replace FORMID with your form ID.
   - Replace FIELDID with your input mask field ID.

   Should look something like this:

   [image: HTML Field Content]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. You helped me a ton! I didn't know the mask feature was a separate script integrated with gravity forms. I went to the link you gave me and checked out which file that code is stored in, and went to the file in gravity forms and edited it. So I ended up finding a quick thanks. Thanks sooo much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you created input by from Gravity form default funcitonaliy "gform_input_masks" as per E.x below.

```
add_filter( 'gform_input_masks', 'add_mask' );
function add_mask( $masks ) {
    $masks['phone number'] = '99999999999';
    return $masks;
}
```

And then you want to removed line from input then you need to use "gform_input_mask_script" as per example below.

```
add_filter( 'gform_input_mask_script', 'set_mask_script', 10, 4 );
function set_mask_script( $script, $form_id, $field_id, $mask ) {
    $script = "jQuery('#input_{$form_id}_{$field_id}').mask('" . esc_js( $mask ) . "',{placeholder:' '}).bind('keypress', function(e){if(e.which == 13){jQuery(this).blur();} } );";
    return $script;
}
```

Please use this and let me know still if you have any problem.